# Trying to recover text I wrote in rapidtables.com's notepad after a hard drive disk error

Tags: cache, chromium, microsoft-edge, recovery

Wrote down some things on that site which uses cookies or cache or whatever to save my text. My hard drive had a disk error and stopped working, so I took it out and connected it externally to a different computer by USB. Where could I find the text I wrote? (Browser was Edge)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It is within reason that the drive damage either prevents access to the disk or damaged the area where your data resided

Comment: @John I was able to recover my other files fine